# Как сместить изображение фона?

Tags: css

допустим изображение 1600х1000 на сайте отведенно для него высота 500пиксилей и отображается оно не полным как можно подвинуть его вверх что бы нижняя часть была видна?

Comment: если вас какой то ответ устроил то отметьте его решением !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
background-position: 50% 100%;
```

Первое значение - расположение фонового изображения по оси х, 50% - оно будет по центру, второе значение - расположение по оси y, 100% - будет от нижнего края элемента.

Answer (score 5):

К примеру: я взял изображение большого размера [вот оно](https://cdn.wallaps.com/wallpapers/150000/144909.jpg)
и есть блок как требуется в ширину 500px и нам нужно сместить фон в нижний правый край то делается это так :

```css
.positionir{
  width:500px;
  height:400px;
  background:url(https://cdn.wallaps.com/wallpapers/150000/144909.jpg);
  background-position:bottom right;
}
```

```html
<div class="positionir"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно, чтобы изображение полностью влезло, то нужно использовать `background-size: contain`, но обычно используют `background-size: cover`, изображение немного обрежется, но оно займет всю площадь контейнера.

[Вот тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) все подробно расписано и наглядно показано.